# Phase difference of two time series

Tags: signal-processing

Consider we have two time series and for each of them , we know the phase (Phase1 and Phase2). We want to compute phase difference between these two time series. We define the phase difference as (Phase1 - Phase2) and we wrap the results to the range of [-pi,pi]. Based on this definition of phase difference, how can we say which signal is leading and which signal is lagging? Is it something we can determine only based on the sign of the phase difference?

For instance, if phase difference is positive (between 0 and +pi), can we say that signal 1 is leading?

Comment: Please describe your problem in more detail. What is the physical meaning of the relative phase? Why is it important which signal "is leading"? In the current form of the question the relative phase could depend on the arbitrary choice of the starting time $t=0s$. Hence, the question "which signal is leading" becomes a matter of choice without physical importance. Why should one spend time on such a question?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about phase difference between two time series, say $\{x_k\}$and$\{y_k\}$ the underlying signal must be something that can be viewed as a "sinusoid" in some approximate sense. If you know nothing else then with a Fourier transform you can estimate the underlying sinusoidal frequency, say you get $\omega$. Now apply to the time series what RF engineers call an IQ (coherent) detection: calculate two sums of products:$ M(x) = \sum_k x_k e^{-\mathfrak j \omega t_k}$ and $ M(y) = \sum_k y_k e^{-\mathfrak j \omega t_k}$, and let $z=M(x) \bar M(y)$ then the phase of $z$ is the estimate of the phase angle between the two time series.

This can be seen as follows. Let $r_k = \rm{cos}(\omega t_k + \phi)+\nu_k$ where $\nu_k$ is noise.
Then $$ M(r) = \sum_k \rm{cos}(\omega t_k + \phi_r) e^{-\mathfrak j \omega t_k} +\rm{noise}\\
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_k [e^{\mathfrak j (\omega t_k + \phi_r)}+e^{-\mathfrak j (\omega t_k + \phi)}] e^{-\mathfrak j \omega t_k}+\rm{noise}\\
=\frac{1}{2}Ne^{\mathfrak j \phi_r} + \sum_k e^{-\mathfrak j (2\omega t_k + \phi_r)}+\rm{noise}\\$$
The sum is nearly zero if many samples are taken over a period, and it is exactly zero if the period is exactly sampled. The rms of the independent noise samples grows like $\sqrt{N}$. In this context $\phi$ is the phase of the signal $r$ relative to the receiver's oscillator. So if you calculate the phases for both signals relative to the local clock (oscillator, sample) then the differecne of those will get you the relative phase between *them*:$M(x)\bar M(y) \propto e^{\mathfrak j (\phi_x - \phi_y)}$